# How do I secure my OPEN APIs?

Tags: ajax, api, rest, security, django-rest-framework

I've an API endpoint hosted (built via Django Rest Framework), for eg:- `domain.com/api/fetch_all?start=0&end=50`. This fetches all the results from the database in a pagination manner.

Now I'm representing this information on a webpage. Its more or less like an open forum where everyone can read the data, but only some can write. I'm viewing this data onto the webpage via an AJAX request hitting the above endpoint. For eg:-

```
$.ajax({
    type:'get',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url:'domain.com/api/fetch_all?start=0&end=50',
    cache : true,
    dataType:'json',
    success:function(data)
    {
        // presenting the information when the page loads.
    }
});
```

So, my questing is how can I secure my APIs, so that no robots can access the data that I'm presenting on my forum. For eg:- if any code/script tries to access my APIs, it should throw `403 Forbidden` error.

```
import requests

# this should return 403 error
response = requests.get('domain.com/api/fetch_all?start=0&end=50')
```

However, if I try to get this data via the browser AJAX request, it should return the data. How can I make sure whether the request is coming from a browser(man-handled) or a robot?

PS: I cannot add OAuth functionality over here, since I dont have a login form.

Comment: If you don't want something "copied" don't make it available to the public. The 'risk' of exposing an API to the public is the same as exposing and HTML to the public, there is no way you can do something about it (if you want it to be public).

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to restrict requesters in this way, because a robot could always add headers to spoof being a browser. Anything you do on your client can be copied by an attacker. Without requiring auth, the best you can do is rate limiting - track requests on a per-client basis, and only allow a certain number of requests per time unit.

A partially-functional solution would be to look at the `User-Agent` header. That should include browser information, and might let you knock out some robots, but not all or even most of them.